# How to download all files from a link by selecting date

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I have a url as mentioned below. I want to select date field and fill in some date and then click on "select all reports" box. Then download all the files from "multiple file download"

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/all-reports-derivatives#cr_deriv_equity_archives'

Is it possible using request or selenium is the only way. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to debug the request in the browser console, there may be a request information for your needs, see if there is a suitable url, and try to use the request to verify the request.
or selenium can do Fulfill your request.

Comment: Can you provide a python code using selenium.

Comment: You can probably do a combination of selenium and pyauto gui for this.

Comment: Can you help me with some basic code?